# How to launch second shiny modal based on an event in the main shiny app ui and a response to first modal

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where an event can and should trigger multiple shinyModals, but it only shows one modal. Here is my app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)


ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select_data_type",
                  "select data type",
                  choices = c("letters", "numbers")),
      uiOutput("select_data"),
      actionButton("add_data", "Add Data")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )

  )
)

server = function(session, input, output) {

  #empty df
  empty_df <- data.frame()

  #reactive to store data
  data <- reactiveVal(empty_df)

  #reactive to store modal dialog btn choice
  confirm_change <- reactiveVal("empty")

  #add data to reactive
  observeEvent(input$add_data, {
    dat <- data.frame(a = input$select_data) %>%
      dplyr::rename(!!sym(input$select_data_type) := a)
    if (nrow(data()) < 1) {
      data(dat)
    } else {
      new_dat <- rbind(data(), dat)
      data(new_dat)
    }
  })

  #output data selector
  output$select_data <- renderUI({
    if (input$select_data_type == "letters") {
      data_choices <- c("A", "B", "C")
    } else {data_choices <- c(1:3)}

    selectizeInput("select_data", "select data", c("", data_choices),
                   selected = NULL,
                   multiple = FALSE)
  })

  #output data table
  output$data <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  #create reactive to store choices
  previous_dtypes <- reactiveValues(prev = NULL)

  #store current and previous data type value in reactive element
  observeEvent(input$select_data_type, {
    previous_dtypes$prev <- c(tail(previous_dtypes$prev, 1), input$select_data_type)
  })

  #if user changes letter, show modal
  observeEvent(input$select_data_type, {
    req(nrow(data()) > 0)

    #here I am attempting to some flow control of sorts to make sure modal isn't triggered endlessly
    if(confirm_change() != "empty") {
      confirm_change("empty") }
    else {
      #modal code
      showModal(modalDialog(
        "Are you sure you want to change your data type?! All data will be deleted!",
        footer = tagList(actionButton("confirm", "Yes, I'm Sure!",
                                      class = "btn-danger"),
                         actionButton("cancel", "Cancel"))
      ))
    }
  })

  #if numbers is selected, show another modal
  observeEvent(input$select_data_type, {
    req(nrow(data()) == 0)
    if (input$select_data_type == "numbers"){
      showModal(modalDialog("UHG, NUMBERS?!"))
    }
  })

  #if confirm, erase all data
  observeEvent(input$confirm, {
    confirm_change(TRUE)
    data(empty_df)
    shinyjs::reset("select_data")
    removeModal()
    confirm_change("empty")
  })

  #if cancel, go back to prevous data type value
  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    confirm_change(FALSE)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "select_data_type",
                      selected = previous_dtypes$prev[1])
    removeModal()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

to reproduce my problem open the app, select any letter from the select data dropdown list, then click add data. Then go back up to the select data type dropdown list and select numbers. A modal will pop up asking to confirm changing the data type. click "yes, I'm sure". It should work but no other modals pop up. What I want is for the the "uhg numbers" modal to pop up.

The "uhg numbers" modal should pop up only if a. the user choses numbers when there is no other data entered, or b. the user changes to numbers and then clicks "yes, I'm sure" button in the confirm data type modal.